# Develop Kinect game using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I want to develop a game using Unity + Kinect, as I understand Unity does not support the official Kinect SDK so I have to find another way. I saw that some guys use ZigFu which seems to not have a good Documentation and has a $200 licence. Is there any other easy way to make things work between Kinect and Unity? If I choose to not use Unity, what other tools exist that support the official C# Kinect SDK to develop a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Official Microsoft Kinect SDK should be easy to plug into the [XNA Game Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23714).

There should [articles](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Tutorial-XNA-40--Kinect-for-Windows-SDK) on the web and samples shipping with the SDK.

Unfortunately I haven't used the MS Kinect SDK since version 1.5. I'm hoping there are updated guides/tutorials available for the latest SDK.

**UPDATE**

One workaround would using multiple applications talking to each via a TCP/UDP socket (OSC is pretty easy to use for example). The idea is you use what you prefer for the kinect tracking, but send a list of coordinates for the joint's positions and orientations to unity.

Comment: There are more tutorials online, but there really aren't that many more in the documentation, besides Kinect Fusion and the new web interface.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, it's been a while since I touched MS SDK. Using a socket to pass the data to unity could work though

Comment: Hmmm, yes hadn't thought of that... Kinda like: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/140864-how-pass-data-using-sockets.html

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza any good tutorial on this TCP/UDP socket solution? thank you.

Comment: Just doing a quick search found a few decent looking results: [Rumen's Kinect with MS-SDK assets](http://rfilkov.com/2013/12/16/kinect-with-ms-sdk/) free on the asset store and listed as tested with kinect sdk 1.7 and 1.8. Other possibly good ones might be: [omicronSDK](https://github.com/uic-evl/omicron), [KinectDaemon](https://github.com/Jerdak/KinectDaemon)

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this unity thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/162075-Connecting-Kinect-Unity-with-Official-SDK). It states that you cannot use the Kinect SDK with Unity, as the frameworks are not correct. However that was a different version.

Actually, it says you can use it as [this sample](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK) shows.

Note that there are many errors people seem to be having with it. I don't know how much of that is people having poor code and how much is with the SDK.